# How to get image attribute with content?

Tags: html, css, css-content

I can get attribute from tag `<a>` but I can not get it from `<img>`. what can i do ?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nV7Lt/1/)

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Some alt"/>
<br/>
<a href="#" alt="Some alt">test link</a>
```

**CSS**

```
img:after{
    content:attr(alt);
    margin-left:10px;
}
a:after{
    content:attr(alt);
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Why not? Which attribute you want to get?

Comment: alt attribute, Demo is in question

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943223/put-title-alt-attributes-into-css-after-content-image

Comment: my problem is with "alt" attribute not other, but thanks

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after), `::after` "matches a virtual last **child** of the selected element", and because [`<img>` can not have child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Summary), it won't have any `::after` or `::before`. Same applies to `<input>` too.

Comment: @Passerby so it is impossible with CSS, right ?

Comment: @Mohsen I believe it is.

Comment: @Mohsen It's not about `content`/`attr()`, it's about `::after`/`::before` can not work with elements that can not have DOM child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the @Passerby comment it is not possible with CSS:

> According to MDN, ::after "matches a virtual last child of the
>   selected element", and because  can not have child, it won't have
>   any ::after or ::before. Same applies to input too.

so I wrote this JQuery code:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nV7Lt/11/)

```
var $imageAlt = '<span class="after">'+$("#image").attr("alt")+'</span>';
$("#image").after($imageAlt);
```